# Initialize sized, static string lists in C

Tags: c, string, struct, static, initialization

I want to create string lists with a discoverable size and am not sure if I have the right method/syntax. Here is my attempt:

```
  typedef struct {
       unsigned int size;
       char** list;
  } STRLIST;

  static STRLIST listMediaType = {
      .size = 7,
      .list = {
          "Book",
          "Map",
          "Booklet",
          "Pamphlet",
          "Magazine",
          "Report",
          "Journal"
      },
  };
```

Is this the right approach? Note that I do not want to hardcode the size into the structure because I want to use the same type to define many different lists. For example, imagine the following function:

```
void printList( STRLIST* pList ){
   for( int x = 0; x < pList->size; x++ ) printf( "%s\n", pList->list );
}
```

Comment: did you even try it first?

Comment: If you just do `char * list[] = {"Book", "Map"...}` you can find out its size just with `sizeof list / sizeof list[0]`, you don't need to wrap it in a `struct` like this. This kind of thing only becomes a problem when you don't know at compile time how many elements you have, and here you do.

Comment: No, I want to use the same structure for different lists of different sizes because of functions that take a "list" as a parameter and different lists could be supplied.

Comment: As an aside: Why can't you just use a simple array of `char*`, with a sentinel-`NULL`?

Comment: @Deduplicator I suppose I could. I didn't think of that. Thats why I am asking the question.

Comment: In the end, it's your decision each time.

Comment: It is certainly more C-like to use a `NULL` sentinel.  As to which is better (size vs. sentinel) , it depends on larger coding goals not presented here and like @Deduplicator, "In the end, it's your decision".  For me, if I used the `size`, I would use type `size_t` rather than `unsigned`.

Comment: @chux I have been thinking about this, and another reason for using size, is that in many contexts I will have to have a numeric iterator anyway. For example, lets say I am printing the number 1,2,3... alongside the values, or lets say I am adding them to some other list, either way I have to keep track of the index value of the list as I traverse it. So, if I am checking for null I am not really saving a variable. Also, it means I have to dereference the array each time through the loop (check memory).

Comment: @Tyler Durden Using `size` instead of the `NULL` sentinel also allows an element of `NULL` in the list.  IAC, there are other Stack Exchange communities well suited for this type of question.  Maybe http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with C99 compound-literals and a slight change:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4497d2645ad21b74

```
typedef struct STRLIST{
    unsigned int size;
    char** list;
} STRLIST;

static STRLIST listMediaType = {
    .size = 7,
    .list = (char*[]){
        "Book",
        "Map",
        "Booklet",
        "Pamphlet",
        "Magazine",
        "Report",
        "Journal"
    },
};
```

Alternative for C90 (thus without compound-literals and designated initializers):   http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cc95d25afc18c91

```
static char* list[] = {
    "Book",
    "Map",
    "Booklet",
    "Pamphlet",
    "Magazine",
    "Report",
    "Journal"
};
static STRLIST listMediaType = {
    sizeof list / sizeof *list,
    // Used sizeof to avoid manually typing the lists length
    list,
};
```

As an aside, an array with a sentinel-`NULL` is far simpler than a counted array.
Does not even need a new type.

```
static char* list[] = {
    "Book",
    "Map",
    "Booklet",
    "Pamphlet",
    "Magazine",
    "Report",
    "Journal",
    0
};
void printList(char** pList){
   while(*pList) printf( "%s\n", *pList++);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `sizeof list / sizeof *list` approach.  The pros/cons of `size` vs. sentinel seems akin to C strings and C++ strings.

Answer (score 1):

You may check this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned int size;
    char* list[];

} STRLIST;

static STRLIST listMediaType = {
    7, 
    {
        "Book",
        "Map",
        "Booklet",
        "Pamphlet",
        "Magazine",
        "Report",
        "Journal"
    }
};

int main() {
    printf("struct size: %d\n", listMediaType.size);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < listMediaType.size; i++) 
        printf("struct elem[%d] = \"%s\"\n", 
                i, 
                listMediaType.list[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

I think there are 2 problems in your approach:

1. Is `TYPEDEF` syntactic correct in C? I think you should write it in lowercase.
2. If you want to initialize a struct, just use the brace and without `.attributes`

Hope this one will help.

Thanks

Comment: Using the attributes allows the code to remain correct, even if the order of fields change without needing to re-code.  It flags an error is the field name is deleted in the .h file.  It also is self documenting.  These 3 effects do not occur when code just uses the brace without attributes.